# @Html.CheckboxFor nor <input> passing checkbox value back to controller (binding issue)

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

So right now I am trying to create a User admin page. The main model for the page is actually an IdentityUser, but the model I am trying to update from the view is an IdentityRole

Here's the view:

```
@model AG.SharedServices.DTO.IdentityUser

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>IdentityUser</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <ul>
                @foreach (var role in TempData["Roles"] as IEnumerable<AG.SharedServices.DTO.IdentityRole>)
                {
                    <li>
                        <input name="@role.Name" type="checkbox" value="@role.Selected" />@role.Name
                    </li>
                }
            </ul>

        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

I've also tried replacing the "`<input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />`" with "`@Html.CheckBoxFor(r => role.Selected)`" But neither have passed back the value of the checkbox, it always returns false. And the CheckBoxFor will not accept any other value rather than IdentityUser, which is an issue and it would help if I knew how to make it accept a different model

Here is the controller.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using AG.SharedServices.DTO;
using System.Data;
using AG.BusinessServices;
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;

namespace AG.AGWeb.Controllers
{
    public class UserAdminController : Controller
    {
        private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;

        public UserAdminController()
        {

        }

        public UserAdminController(ApplicationUserManager userManager)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
        }

        public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
        {
            get
            {
                return _userManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
            }
            private set
            {
                _userManager = value;
            }
        }
        // GET: UserAdmin
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var users = UserManager.Users;
            return View(users);
        }

        // GET: UserAdmin/Details/5
        public ActionResult Details(int id)
        {
            return View();
        }

        // GET: UserAdmin/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: UserAdmin/Create
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(FormCollection collection)
        {
            try
            {
                // TODO: Add insert logic here

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }

        // GET: UserAdmin/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(string id)
        {
            var user = UserManager.FindById(id);
            var roleService = new RoleService();
            var roles = roleService.GetRoles();
            //add code to check users roles
            var userRoles = UserManager.GetRoles(id);
            foreach(var role in roles)
            {
                role.Selected = userRoles.Contains(role.Name);
            }
            TempData["Roles"] = roles;
            TempData.Keep("Roles");
            return View(user);
        }

        // POST: UserAdmin/Edit/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Edit")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(IdentityUser model, string id)
        {
            try
            {
                // TODO: Add update logic here
                if (model == null)
                {
                    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
                }
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    var user = UserManager.FindById(id);
                    user.FirstName = model.FirstName;
                    user.LastName = model.LastName;
                    user.PhoneNumber = model.PhoneNumber;
                    var results = await UserManager.UpdateAsync(user);
                    if (results.Succeeded)
                    {
                        var roles = TempData["Roles"] as IEnumerable<IdentityRole>;
                        foreach(var role in roles)
                        {
                            if (role.Selected && await UserManager.IsInRoleAsync(id, role.Id) == false)
                            {
                                await UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(id, role.Id);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                await UserManager.RemoveFromRoleAsync(id, role.Id);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }

                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }

        // GET: UserAdmin/Delete/5
        public ActionResult Delete(string id)
        {
            var user = UserManager.FindById(id);
            return View(user);
        }

        // POST: UserAdmin/Delete/5
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Delete(int id, FormCollection collection)
        {
            try
            {
                // TODO: Add delete logic here

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the Model we are trying to pass is, IdentityRole, looks like this:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AG.SharedServices.DTO
{
    public class IdentityRole : IRole
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Default constructor for Role 
        /// </summary>
        public IdentityRole()
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor that takes names as argument 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="name"></param>
        public IdentityRole(string name)
            : this()
        {
            Name = name;
        }

        public IdentityRole(string name, string id)
        {
            Name = name;
            Id = id;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Role ID
        /// </summary>
        public string Id { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Role name
        /// </summary>
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public bool Selected { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to how I can take that foreach loop in the view to pass in the IdentityRoles and change the Selected value of the role in order to Assign a user to a role?

Thanks!

Comment: Your not using `CheckBoxFor()` anywhere in your view (review your question title). You just creating a collection of chekboxes with names that have no relationship at all to your model so they will never bind to anything. Use a view model that represents what you need to edit.

Comment: See the most recent edit, I added the code we tried to use with `CheckBoxFor()`

Comment: Make no difference - your not generating inputs that relate to your model. And in any case you cannot use a `foreach` loop (it needs to be a `for` loop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use something like UserIdentityModel with array of Roles in your actions

```
public class UserIdentityModel
{
   ...

   public IList<IdentityRole> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

and create a list of roles on your View

```
   @model UserIdentityModel
   ...
   <ul>
       @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Roles.Count; i++)
       {
          <li>
             <input name="@("Roles[" + i + "].Selected")" type="checkbox" value="@(Model.Roles[i].Selected)" />@Model.Roles[i].Name
             <input type="hidden" name="@("Roles[" + i + "].Name")" value="@(Model.Roles[i].Name)">
             <input type="hidden" name="@("Roles[" + i + "].Id")" value="@(Model.Roles[i].Id)">
          </li>
       }
    </ul>
```

In your post action you will receive UserIdentityModel with collection of roles

```
public ActionResult Edit(string id)
{
   var user = UserManager.FindById(id);
   var model = new UserIdentityModel();
   ///Fill all fields of the model      
   return View(model);
}

// POST: UserAdmin/Edit/5
[HttpPost, ActionName("Edit")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(UserIdentityModel model)
{
   ...
   foreach(var role in model.Roles)
   {
      ...
   }
```

Comment: This is actually what we ended up doing! Thank you though, great answer!

Comment: Awful way to generate your html - :) use `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Roles[i].Name)`. But if OP really is generating a whole lot of hidden inputs for a collection, then its just degrading performance and opening up to overposting attacks.